# MySQL insert errors

Tags: php, mysql

It's pretty much one of my first times working with MYSQL, and I can't seem to fix this one error I keep getting. I'm trying to store data to a table which has an auto_increment on its id (first column).
The error I keep getting is this:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'voorletters ='asd', tussenvoegsel ='', achternaam ='', roepnaam ='', adres ='', ' at line 1"

I just filled the textboxes with a little bit of rubish, there are no columns that require data either. Here is the code I use:

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $voorletters = $_POST['voorletters'];
    $tussenvoegsel = $_POST['tussenvoegsel'];
    $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
    $roepnaam = $_POST['roepnaam'];
    $adres = $_POST['adres'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $plaats = $_POST['plaats'];
    $geslacht = $_POST['geslacht'];
    $emailadres = $_POST['emailadres'];
    $telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
    $mobielenummer = $_POST['mobielenummer'];
    $geboortedatum = $_POST['geboortedatum'];
    $bsn = $_POST['bsn'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `naw` "
            . "voorletters ='$voorletters', "
            . "tussenvoegsel ='$tussenvoegsel', "
            . "achternaam ='$achternaam', "
            . "roepnaam ='$roepnaam', "
            . "adres ='$adres', "
            . "postcode ='$postcode', "
            . "plaats ='$plaats', "
            . "geslacht ='$geslacht', "
            . "emailadres ='$emailadres', "
            . "telefoonnummer ='$telefoonnummer', "
            . "mobielenummer ='$mobielenummer', "
            . "geboortedatum ='$geboortedatum', "
            . "bsn ='$bsn' "
            . "WHERE id = '$id'")
            or die(mysql_error());
```

If this isn't enough information, please tell me. I've tried a lot of things, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: RTM's http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: INSERT doesn't use a WHERE. Either delete the where or change your command to UPDATE

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove the WHERE, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm just starting with MySQL and I have troubles with learning new things, it doesn't really seem that simple to me ;p. But I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: You'll get there @SapphireFox...we all started just like you!

Comment: Thanks for the support ^-^!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mix up `insert` and `update` syntax. Replace

```
INSERT INTO `naw` voorletters ='$voorletters'...
```

with

```
UPDATE `naw` set voorletters ='$voorletters'....
```

And you should really use *Prepared Statements* to avoid syntax errors and SQL injections due to user input.

Comment: Actually MySQL does have an `INSERT ... SET` syntax—the OP is just missing the keyword `SET`.

Comment: Thanks! the 'set' fixed it for me ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Just use following code. Make sure that you are inserting data for every field sequentially-

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `naw` VALUES(
            '".$voorletters."',
            '".$tussenvoegsel."',
            '".$achternaam."',
            '".$roepnaam."',
            '".$adres."',
            '".$postcode."',
            '".$plaats."',
            '".$geslacht."',
            '".$emailadres."',
            '".$telefoonnummer."',
            '".$mobielenummer."',
            '".$geboortedatum."',
            '".$bsn."')")
            or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Insert does not have a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong syntax

The `INSERT` syntax is

```
INSERT INTO `YourTableName`(`Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3`, `Field4)
VALUES ('value-1','value-2','value-3','value-4')
```

The `UPDATE` syntax is

```
UPDATE `YourTableName` 
SET `Field1`='value-1',`Field2`='value-2',`Field3`='value-3',`Field4`='value-4'
WHERE YourConditions
```

Comment: Actually MySQL does have an `INSERT ... SET` syntax—the OP is just missing the keyword `SET`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `` around naw, it's ok in phpmyadmin but quite messy almost every where else.
And you souldn't concatenate every line, do it in one "..." and use backspace to make it more readable.

So:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO naw
            VALUES('$voorletters', 
                    '$tussenvoegsel',
                    ... ,
                     WHERE id = '$id'");//you can't do that, maybe you should use an UPDATE
```

Comment: Will it still work the same as now without the quotes?